# How to use Scrubty properly to grab URL from the XML outputted content

Tags: ruby, xml, web-scraping, scrubyt

I am by no means a master with Ruby and am quite new to Scrubyt. I was just trying out some examples found on there wiki page. The example i was working on was getting the search results returned by Google when you search for 'ruby' and I had the idea of grabbing the URL of each result so I could go ahead and fetch that page as well. The problem is I don't know how to grab the URL appropriately. This is my following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'scrubyt'

google_data = Scrubyt::Extractor.define do
  fetch 'http://www.google.com/ncr'
  fill_textfield 'q','ruby'
  submit

  link_title "//a[@class='l']", :write_text => true do
    link_url
  end
end

google_data.to_xml.write($stdout, 1);
```

The code prints out the XML data appropriately (name and link) but how do I retrieve the link without the `<link_url>` tags that seems to get added to it (I tried to print out link_url and I noticed the tags are printed as well). Could I do something as simple as `fetch link_url` or is there a way of extracting the text from the xml content held in `link_url`?

This is some of the content that gets printed by the `google_data.to_xml.write()`:

```
<root>
  <link_title>
    Ruby Programming Language
    <link_url>http://ruby-lang.org/</link_url>
  </link_title>
  <link_title>
    Download Ruby
    <link_url>http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/</link_url>
  </link_title>
  <link_title>
    Ruby - The Inspirational Weight Loss Journey on the Style Network ...
    <link_url>http://www.mystyle.com/mystyle/shows/ruby/index.jsp</link_url>
  </link_title>
  <link_title>
    Ruby (programming language) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
    <link_url>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)</link_url>
  </link_title>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think about alternatives. Scrubyt hasn't been updated in a while, and the forums have been shut down.

[Mechanize](http://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize) can do what the Extractor does, [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) can parse XML or HTML responses, and Builder can create XML (though it seems like you don't really want XML).